# How to create an equation of a given form with integer coefficients and variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A math textbook gives the following problem:
What is the solution of $3(2x-1) - 2(3x+4) = 11x$.
The solution is an integer.

Using Excel to choose some numbers at random and compute the remaining numbers, I want to create problems like that one, with coefficients and solutions that are integers. Rightly or wrongly, I’ve conceptualized my task like this:

- $a(bx + c) + d(ex + f) = gx$
- $abx + ac + dex + df = gx$
- $ac + df = - abx - dex + gx$
- $ac + df = (-ab - de + g)x$
- $(ac + df) / (-ab - de + g) = x$

So if we arbitrarily choose values of $a, b, d, e, g$ and $x$, we can solve for the numerator. For example, if $a=2, b=3, d=5, e=7,$ and $g=11,$ then the denominator is $-30$. If we choose $x=3$, then the numerator is $3*(-30) = -90.$

- (ac + df) = -90
- 2c + 5f = -90

Somehow I’m stuck on that last step. How do I pick values of c and f so that this works? Of course I don’t want just an example of values of c and f that solve here, but a general approach that will give values that are integers.

Or can you suggest a better approach to the original problem?

Comment: You could write a LHS, fix a value for $x$ and finally adjust the RHS accordingly.

Comment: @user I don't follow. Can you say it in baby talk? Are you taking up the solution in the question where I left off? That's Left Hand Sum and Right Hand Sum? Didn't I "fix a value for x" when I chose x=3? What do I do next in the approach in my question?

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$a(bx + c) + d(ex + f) = gx \iff (ab+de)x+(ac+df)=gx$$

therefore we need

- for $ab+de=0$ and $ac+df=0$ we have $x=0$
- for $ab+de=0$ and $ac+df\neq0$ we have $x=\frac{ac+df}{g}$
- for $ab+de\neq 0$ and $ac+df=0$ we have $x=1$ with $g=ab+de$
- for $ab+de\neq 0$ and $ac+df\neq 0$ we have $x=\frac{ac+df}{g-(ab+de)}$

The first and third cases are trivial. For the second one one solution is given by $g=\pm 1$, otherwise we need that $ac+df$ is not prime. For the latter case we can proceed by inspection making $g-(ab+de)=\pm 1$ or for $ac+df$ not prime finding a numerical solution with $|g-(ab+de)|<|ac+df|$.

Comment: Where did that expression 5x2 - 3x + 20 come from? And 19x - 1?

Comment: The idea is to invent or choose arbitrarly a LHS (linear, polynomial or more complicated expression) then fix an integer value for $x$ such that also the LHS is an integer and then choose arbitrarly a RHS=LHS for the fixed value of $x$. It seems the simplest way to create integer equations to me.

Comment: @Chaim Note that polynomial expressions with integer coefficients will always return intger value. As an alternative we could use ceiling or floor functions.

Comment: I think that I follow you now. But the original problem in the text book is linear, and there is no constant on the right side. So it's different from your example in several ways.

Comment: @Chaim This is just an example for the method. We can use the same method for the general form you are looking for. For example: $$10(x-2)-3(x+1)-1=4x$$ has solution $x=8$.

Comment: Right. But you've just moved your constant to the left side of the equals sign. The form in the book is harder to match because there is no such constant. There's one inside each pair of parenthesis and none elsewhere.

Comment: @Chaim Ah ok now I see what you are looking for!

Comment: @Chaim I update the answer.

Comment: @Chaim I've made a general discussion for different possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's really no reason to work forwards - we can work backwards. That is, choose a value for x, such as x=10. We can then perform arbitrary operations on both sides of this equation, such as multiplying or subtracting. We can deliberately choose these operations to preserve integer coefficients, and obviously the solution will remain 10.

Comment: How do I preserve integer coefficients?

Comment: Examples: Multiplying by only integers on both sides, adding/subtracting integers on both sides.

Comment: Can you show me how these comments produce a few equations like the one in the text book?

Comment: Suppose that x=-1. 

Multiply by 11:
11x=-11

Add 6x-6x to both sides (which is just 0):
11x+6x-6x=-11+6x-6x

Simplify the left hand side
11x=-11+6x-6x

Split -11 up and rearrange the right hand side
11x=6x-3-6x-8

Group terms and factor
11x=3(2x-1)-2(3x+4)

This is identical to the provided equation.

Comment: Right. But I've already got that one example. I'm hoping to generate further examples. The reason I provided the form involving variables from a to g (and x) was to explain the sort of equation I'm hoping to generate. I'm looking for new equations that are true when all variables are simply replaced with integers and math symbols are not otherwise rearranged.